# How to integrate a themeforest theme in Blazor web assembly?

Tags: themes, blazor-webassembly

I am creating a new Blazor web assembly pwa app. I have bought a theme from themeforest and trying to integrate it in my Blazor web assembly app. I am using visual studio and .net core 3.1.202. I was able to get the layout UI to work but my side navigation is not working. I am unable to collapse or expand any menu option or even clicking on the hamburger icon doesn't work. I couldn't figure out what I have missed. There are no errors in the console window of the browser. Hence, I request help in this matter. Thanks in advance.

This is what my index.razor page looks like:

[image: index.razor]

This is my wwwroot folder:

[image: wwwroot folder]

Screenshot of console window:

[image: Screenshot of console window]

This is my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="fixed sidebar-light" data-style-switcher-options="{'sidebarColor': 'light'}">

<head>

    <!-- Basic -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Light Sidebar Layout | Porto Admin - Responsive HTML5 Template</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="HTML5 Admin Template" />
    <meta name="description" content="Porto Admin - Responsive HTML5 Template">
    <meta name="author" content="okler.net">

    <!-- Mobile Metas -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <!-- Web Fonts  -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800|Shadows+Into+Light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/animate/animate.compat.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/font-awesome/css/all.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/boxicons/css/boxicons.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" />

    <!-- Specific Page Vendor CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.theme.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap-multiselect/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/morris/morris.css" />

    <!--(remove-empty-lines-end)-->
    <!-- Theme CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css" />


    <!--(remove-empty-lines-end)-->
    <!-- Theme Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css">

    <!-- Head Libs -->
    <!--<script src="vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="master/style-switcher/style.switcher.localstorage.js"></script>-->

    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="manifest.json" rel="manifest" />

</head>

<body>

    <app>Loading...</app>

    <div id="blazor-error-ui">
        An unhandled error has occurred.
        <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
        <a class="dismiss"></a>
    </div>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js');</script>

    <!-- Head Libs -->
    <script src="vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>

    <!-- Vendor -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery-browser-mobile/jquery.browser.mobile.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery-cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="master/style-switcher/style.switcher.js"></script>-->
    <script src="vendor/popper/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/common/common.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/nanoscroller/nanoscroller.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery-placeholder/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>

    <!-- Specific Page Vendor -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqueryui-touch-punch/jquery.ui.touch-punch.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery-appear/jquery.appear.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap-multiselect/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery.easy-pie-chart/jquery.easypiechart.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/flot.tooltip/jquery.flot.tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.pie.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.categories.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/raphael/raphael.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/morris/morris.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/gauge/gauge.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/snap.svg/snap.svg.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/liquid-meter/liquid.meter.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqvmap/data/jquery.vmap.sampledata.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.world.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.africa.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.asia.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.australia.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.europe.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.north-america.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/jqvmap/maps/continents/jquery.vmap.south-america.js"></script>


    <!--(remove-empty-lines-end)-->
    <!-- Theme Base, Components and Settings -->
    <script src="js/theme.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme Custom -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme Initialization Files -->
    <script src="js/theme.init.js"></script>
    <!-- Analytics to Track Preview Website -->
    <script>
        (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
        ga('create', 'UA-42715764-8', 'auto');
        ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>

    <script>
        // Maintain Scroll Position
        if (typeof localStorage !== 'undefined') {
            if (localStorage.getItem('sidebar-left-position') !== null) {
                var initialPosition = localStorage.getItem('sidebar-left-position'),
                    sidebarLeft = document.querySelector('#sidebar-left .nano-content');

                sidebarLeft.scrollTop = initialPosition;
            }
        }
    </script>

    <!-- Examples -->
    <script src="js/examples/examples.dashboard.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

My MainLayout.razor

```html
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<section class="body">
    <!-- start: header -->
    <header class="header">
        <div class="logo-container">
            <a href="/" class="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" width="75" height="35" alt="Porto Admin" />
            </a>
            <div class="d-md-none toggle-sidebar-left" data-toggle-class="sidebar-left-opened" data-target="html" data-fire-event="sidebar-left-opened">
                <i class="fas fa-bars" aria-label="Toggle sidebar"></i>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- start: search & user box -->
        <div class="header-right">
            <span class="separator"></span>

            <div id="userbox" class="userbox">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <figure class="profile-picture">
                        <img src="img/!logged-user.jpg" alt="Joseph Doe" class="rounded-circle" data-lock-picture="img/!logged-user.jpg" />
                    </figure>
                    <div class="profile-info" data-lock-name="John Doe" data-lock-email="johndoe@okler.com">
                        <span class="name">John Doe Junior</span>
                        <span class="role">Administrator</span>
                    </div>

                    <i class="fa custom-caret"></i>
                </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-2">
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="pages-user-profile.html"><i class="bx bx-user-circle"></i> My Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#" data-lock-screen="true"><i class="bx bx-lock"></i> Lock Screen</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="pages-signin.html"><i class="bx bx-power-off"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end: search & user box -->
    </header>
    <!-- end: header -->

    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <NavMenu />

        <section role="main" class="content-body">
            <header class="page-header">
                <h2>Light Sidebar Layout</h2>

                <div class="right-wrapper text-right">
                    <ol class="breadcrumbs">
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html">
                                <i class="bx bx-home-alt"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><span>Layouts</span></li>
                        <li><span>Light Sidebar</span></li>
                    </ol>

                    <a class="sidebar-right-toggle disabled"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                </div>
            </header>

            <!-- start: page -->
            @Body
        </section>
    </div>

</section>
```

My NavMenu.razor

```html
<!-- start: sidebar -->
<aside id="sidebar-left" class="sidebar-left">

<div class="sidebar-header">
    <div class="sidebar-title">
        Navigation
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-toggle d-none d-md-block" data-toggle-class="sidebar-left-collapsed" data-target="html" data-fire-event="sidebar-left-toggle">
        <i class="fas fa-bars" aria-label="Toggle sidebar"></i>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="nano">
    <div class="nano-content">
        <nav id="menu" class="nav-main" role="navigation">

            <ul class="nav nav-main">
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-default.html">
                        <i class="bx bx-home-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span>Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-parent">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <i class="bx bx-cart-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span>eCommerce</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-children">
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-dashboard.html">
                                Dashboard
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-products-list.html">
                                Products List
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-products-form.html">
                                Products Form
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-category-list.html">
                                Categories List
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-category-form.html">
                                Category Form
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-coupons-list.html">
                                Coupons List
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-coupons-form.html">
                                Coupons Form
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-orders-list.html">
                                Orders List
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-orders-detail.html">
                                Orders Detail
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-customers-list.html">
                                Customers List
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="ecommerce-customers-form.html">
                                Customers Form
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="mailbox-folder.html">
                        <span class="float-right badge badge-primary">182</span>
                        <i class="bx bx-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span>Mailbox</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-parent nav-expanded nav-active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <i class="bx bx-layout" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <span>Layouts</span>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-children">
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">
                                Landing Page
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-default.html">
                                Default
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-modern.html">
                                Modern
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-parent">
                            <a>
                                Boxed
                            </a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-children">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-boxed.html">
                                        Static Header
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-boxed-fixed-header.html">
                                        Fixed Header
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-parent">
                            <a>
                                Horizontal Menu Header
                            </a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-children">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-header-menu.html">
                                        Pills
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-header-menu-stripe.html">
                                        Stripe
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-header-menu-top-line.html">
                                        Top Line
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-dark.html">
                                Dark
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-dark-header.html">
                                Dark Header
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-two-navigations.html">
                                Two Navigations
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-parent">
                            <a>
                                Tab Navigation
                            </a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-children">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-tab-navigation-dark.html">
                                        Tab Navigation Dark
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-tab-navigation.html">
                                        Tab Navigation Light
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-tab-navigation-boxed.html">
                                        Tab Navigation Boxed
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-active">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-light-sidebar.html">
                                Light Sidebar
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-left-sidebar-collapsed.html">
                                Left Sidebar Collapsed
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-left-sidebar-scroll.html">
                                Left Sidebar Scroll
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-parent">
                            <a>
                                Left Sidebar Big Icons
                            </a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-children">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-left-sidebar-big-icons.html">
                                        Left Sidebar Big Icons Dark
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-left-sidebar-big-icons-light.html">
                                        Left Sidebar Big Icons Light
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-parent">
                            <a>
                                Left Sidebar Panel
                            </a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-children">
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-left-sidebar-panel.html">
                                        Left Sidebar Panel Dark
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-left-sidebar-panel-light.html">
                                        Left Sidebar Panel Light
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="nav-link" href="layouts-square-borders.html">
                                Square Borders
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
</aside>
<!-- end: sidebar -->
```

Comment: Did you succeed with that? I need exactly the same actually I guess I have the same template. Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a theme from themeforest. The problem was, that all event handlers defined in theme js file are not fired by the frontend.

My solution was to find out what css things changes for an event (for example collapse menu) and to write a java script function that does that DOM maniupulation. Then I'm using JS Interopt from Blazor to call that function. Basically I rewrite all needed JS handlers by hand and call it by for example @onclick handlers in razor components.

A lot of work to do, but it works.

UPDATE:

Most of my theme components are triggered by a DOMContentLoaded event, so a simple manual call of this event is enough. I created following JS function in my custom.js file

```
function triggerThemeJS() {
    window.document.dispatchEvent(new Event("DOMContentLoaded", {
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true
    }));
}
```

and call this with JS Interopt from Blazor Razor page (for example MainLayout):

```
@inject IJSRuntime javaScript

...

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender)
    {
        await javaScript.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerThemeJS");
    }
}
```